# append two plotly offline iplots into one iplot

Tags: python, plotly

I have the following dataset:

```
month   is_member   not_member
0   April   84  7
1   August  292 85
2   July    353 125
3   June    260 35
4   May 238 42
5   November    74  6
6   October 219 29
7   September   288 36
```

I have plotted two separate graphs but cannot find guidance on how to combine them and show two lines on one graph

I understand this might be a basic question but I would appreciate the help

```
import cufflinks as cf
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, 
iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
cf.go_offline()
%matplotlib inline
```

graph1:

```
trace1 = MPVT.iplot(kind='line',x='month',y='not_member', color='white', 
theme='solar', mode='markers+lines',title='bike demand by month for non- 
members')
```

graph2:

```
trace2 = MPVT.iplot(kind='line',x='month',y='is_member', color='gold', 
theme = 'solar', mode='lines')
```

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code below should work:

**Import libraries**

```
import datetime
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from plotly import __version__
%matplotlib inline

import plotly.offline as pyo
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import iplot

import cufflinks as cf
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot 
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

cf.go_offline()
```

**Create sample dataframe**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'month': ['April', 'August', 'July', 'June', 'May', 'November', 'October', 'September'],
    'is_member': [84, 292, 353, 260, 238, 74, 219, 288],
    'not_member': [7, 85, 125, 35, 42, 6, 29, 36]
}
)
df
```

**Create plot**

```
df.iplot(kind='line',x='month',y=['not_member', 'is_member'], color=['white', 'gold'], 
theme='solar', mode='markers+lines',title='Bike demand by month')
```

[image]